# Java - Saving file from JAR to disk

Tags: java, file, fileutils

I'm trying to save a YAML formatted file packaged in the JAR to the user's disk.

The file is named config.yml and sits directly under one of the project's source folders.  I can confirm that the file is packaged in the JAR with WinRAR.

I am using the following code to get the file from the JAR:

```
File file = new File(this.getClassLoader().getResource("config.yml").getPath());
```

And I am using this code to copy the file to a directory:

```
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(file, this.getDataFolder());
```

The getDataFolder() method is implemented by a reliable 3rd party API.
However, when I use a file instance defined with the same getDataFolder() File instance and the path "config.yml":

```
new File(this.getDataFolder(), "config.yml")
```

The console logs a FileNotFoundException.
The file path given in the stack trace is this: "file:\C:\Users\Evan\Desk
top\Test%20Server\plugins\lottocrates-1.0.jar!\config.yml" which seems correct. I tried opening the file with run prompt, which I was able to open the JAR with, but not the config.yml file.

Comment: `file:\C:\Users\Evan\Desk top\Test%20Server\plugins\lottocrates-1.0.jar!\config.yml` is trying to reference the `config.yml` from inside the `lottocrates-1.0.jar` as a `File`, which is obviously wrong.  This `File file = new File(this.getClassLoader().getResource("config.yml").getPath());` is your first problem. Use `Class#getResourceAsStream` to get a `InputStream` to the resource, copy the contents out to a `File` and then load the file, and no, this is not what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked perfectly.  I ended up using CommonsIO to make it fairly painless. (FileUtils#copyInputStreamToFile)